# django request.GET in models

Tags: django, filter, models

Is it possible in Django to have models method with request.GET ? 
e.g.

```
    class Car(models.Model):
        owner = ForeignKey(Owner)
        car_model = ...
        def car_filter(self, request):
            query = request.GET.get("q")
            if query:
                Car.objects.filter(owner = self.id.order_by('id')
            else:
                Car.objects.filter(owner = me).order_by('id'

)
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Purely technically speaking, sure, you can - as long as you can pass the request object from the view. The example code you've posted is syntactically incorrect, but, something like this is technically possible. You just have to make sure that the method is class-method, not instance-method one (since you don't have any instances in this case):

```
class Car(models.Model):
   ...
   @classmethod
   def get_by_owner(cls, request):
       query = request.GET.get("q")
       if query:
           return cls.objects.filter(owner=query)
       elif request.user.is_authenticated():
           return cls.objects.all()

def your_view(request):
    cars = Car.get_by_owner(request)
    ...
```

However, **DON'T DO THIS**. It's a bad idea because you're moving your request processing logic to a model. Models should only care about the data, and user request handling is view's job.

So, I'd suggest to have all the logic in the views:

```
def your_view(request):
    cars = Car.objects.all().order_by("id")
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        cars = cars.filter(owner=query)
    ...
```

If you need some complicated logic, that a lot of views would share, you can use [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/managers/):

```
class CarManager(model.Manager):
    def owned(self, username=None):
        queryset = super(CarManager, self).get_query_set()
        if username:
            user = Owner.objects.get(username=username)
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner=user)
        return queryset

class Car(models.Model):
   ...
   objects = CarManager()

...
def your_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    cars = Car.objects.owned(query)
    ...
```

Comment: you cannot call `Car.car_filter(request)`, since model methods work in row level, it must be called with an object. Table/model level call is done via Managers

Comment: @doniyor you're absolutely right, I've made a wrong answer. Sorry! Fixed this with `@classmethod`. Now it should be correct (although I still don't suggest to do things this way, especially passing request objects - Managers are more cleanlier solution)

Comment: The only reason why I want to do it is becayse I want to display related objects for each CAR object. I want to perform some filters on these related objects. So, e.g. for each CAR for each CAR related object do some filters. How can I do it better in Django instead of trying to have a method with filter in model class ?

Comment: @BlueDog I'd suggest to see the model managers example and linked documentation for the further details. Put the actual filtering logic to the custom model manager, but only pass the actual filter values there (e.g. the owner name or an already-parsed datetime) - not the request object containing those. Keep all `request.GET.get` (or alike) in view code - this is view-specific stuff - as in the future you may need some view where parameters have to be passed or named differently.

Answer (score 2):

Possible, but you have to pass the `request` manually:

```
# inside your views
qs_ = car_object.car_filter(request)
```

but I dont see any sense in doing so.

Everything that has to do with `request` should go into views which is the place for request-response flow.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can handle this stuff in your view only

```
def yourview(self, request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
       Car.objects.filter(owner = self.id).order_by('id')
    else:
       Car.objects.filter(owner = me).order_by('id')
```

else other wise you have to send your request object to the model function from your view.

Comment: what if I have a view which passes context data e.g. 'cars' to my template and in template I do for ... loop : for eachcar in cars display eachcar.related_object AND now I want to filter all related_object globaly by e.g. DATE that I post from another view to the view that handles above mentioned context data ? At the moment the only way I see to filter these related_objects is to POST chosen DATE to my models to the related_objects CLASS because I see no way to filter these related_objects in the above mentioned view with context data because I do not refer directly to related_objects there